# Who created this shloka? "kar charan krutam va kayajm karmajm va"

Tags: shiva, identification-request, shloka

Who created this shloka? What is its source?

करचरण कृतं वाक्कायजं कर्मजं वा ।
श्रवणनयनजं वा मानसं वापराधं ।
विहितमविहितं वा सर्वमेतत्क्षमस्व ।
जय जय करुणाब्धे श्रीमहादेव शम्भो ॥

karacharaNa kRRitaM vAkkAyajaM karmajaM vA | shravaNanayanajaM vA mAnasaM vAparAdhaM | vihitamavihitaM vA sarvametatkShamasva | jaya jaya karuNAbdhe shrImahAdeva shambho ||

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the 14th Sloka of [Adi Shankara's Shiva Aparadha Kshamapana stotram.](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Shiva_Aparadha_Kshamapana_Stotram)

> Kara-charana-kritam vaak,-kaaya-jam, karma-jam vaa,
>   Shravana-nayana-jam vaa, maanasam vaa-aparaadhama,
>  Vihitam-avihitam
>   vaa, sarvam-etat-kshmasva,
>  Shiva shiva karunaabdhe, shrii mahaadeva
>   shambho||
>
> Whatever faults or mistakes I have done so far with the help of my
>   hands, legs, speech and body, also due to my actions, also by seeing
>   and hearing or may be mentally or as per the injunctions of Veda, all
>   these Oh Lord Shiva who is all compassionate please forgive me. You
>   are the Lord of all deities and one who nature is to bless all., 14

Devotees of Lord Shiva often recite it after completion of a worship, asking for his forgiveness for all the mistakes that they might have committed.

**NOTE:** "Aparadha" means "offence or guilt" and "Kshamapana" means "asking for forgiveness". Also, in the Sloka you gave it's "Jaya Jaya Karunabdhe" where as in my version it's "Shiva Shiva...". And, this could be due to "Pathabheda" or alternate reading.

Comment: Nice, I also find it as the last sloka in [Shiva Manasa Pooja](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_shiva/smaanasa.html?lang=sa) by Adi Shankaracharya

Comment: @Pandya So Shankaracharya himself used the variant in another of his stotram.

Comment: Which Shastra or other book is this Stotram in?

Comment: @hindustudent This Stotra is not from any scripture. It was composed by Adi Shankaracharya. You may find it in books on Stotras.

Comment: Dhanyawaad @Rickross ji